# Webcam image live processing

Tags: algorithm, webcam

need to perform processing of webcam image - image should be captured, processed and displayed live. Could you recommend programming language? Already dobne with Delphi tsCap32 and java, but its runs slowly. Is there any solutions in other languages?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try using C/C++ and [OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/). It is fast and has a large community. A good starting point is to read the book: ["Learning OpenCV"](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920022497.do)